Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Shield\Authentication\Authentication::isLoggedIn()
`I'm encountering an error in my CodeIgniter 4.5.4 application while using CodeIgniter Shield for authentication. The error message is:
Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Shield\Authentication\Authentication::loggedIn()
It seems like loggedIn() is not a method available in the CodeIgniter\Shield\Authentication\Authentication class. According to the documentation I reviewed, the correct method to check authentication status might be different.
Questions:
What is the correct method to check if a user is logged in using CodeIgniter Shield?
How should I modify my code to replace the loggedIn() method with the appropriate method?
Any help or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!`
Here's a snippet of my Home controller:
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Client\ClientExceptionInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\Shield\Authentication\Authentication;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Get the Shield authentication instance
        $auth = service('authentication');

        // Check if the user is logged in
        if (!$auth->isLoggedIn()) {
            // If not logged in, redirect to the login page
            return redirect()->to('login');
        }

        // If the user is logged in, proceed with fetching GitHub repository details
        try {
            $repos = $this->github->getRepos();

            // Prepare data for the view
            $data = [
                'pageTitle'        => 'Welcome to News Hub',
                'html_url'         => $repos['framework4']->html_url,
                'stargazers_count' => number_format($repos['codeigniter4']->stargazers_count),
                'forks_count'      => number_format($repos['codeigniter4']->forks_count),
            ];
        } catch (ClientExceptionInterface $e) {
            // Log error and prepare fallback data
            log_message('error', '[' . __METHOD__ . '] ' . get_class($e) . ': ' . $e->getMessage());

            $data = [
                'pageTitle'        => 'Welcome to News Hub',
                'html_url'         => 'https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4',
                'stargazers_count' => '',
                'forks_count'      => '',
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle any other exceptions
            log_message('error', '[' . __METHOD__ . '] ' . get_class($e) . ': ' . $e->getMessage());

            $data = [
                'pageTitle'        => 'Welcome to News Hub',
                'html_url'         => 'https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4',
                'stargazers_count' => '',
                'forks_count'      => '',
            ];
        }

        // Render the view with the fetched data
        return view('home', $data); // Replace 'home' with your desired view
    }
}


Like this? loggedIn() != isLoggedIn()
